# Casting to an array or dictionary type when subscripting context:Any

Tags: swift

I'm already aware that the data I get when I subscript `context:Any` has the *Any* type. I'm trying to make sure that data supports subscripting such as an array or dictionary.

I've tried casting to  array and dictionary types without success and read many questions related to subscripting and casting but none of them illustrate the use of subscripting `context:Any`. What do I need to do?

```
public var recieverNumber = ""
public var recieverName = ""

class Messenger: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

@IBAction func send() {
    let newNumber = recieverNumber.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")
    let escapedString = message.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
    WKExtension.shared().openSystemURL(URL(string: "sms:&recipients=\(newNumber)&body=\(escapedString)")!)

    recieverNumber = ""
    recieverName = ""
    // ...code...
    dismiss()
}

@IBAction func contacts() {
    recieverNumber = ""
    recieverName = ""
    // ...code...
    dismiss()
}

// ...code...

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
    // ...code...
    recieverName = context![0] as! String // error
    recieverNumber = context![1] as! String // error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way is to conditional downcast `Any?` to the expected type (a `String` array)

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
    guard let receiver = context as? [String], receiver.count > 1 else { return }
    recieverName = receiver[0]
    recieverNumber = receiver[1]
}
```